# Overwrite variable from makefile

Tags: makefile

In my makefile I have a variable `FOO`:

```
FOO = /path/to/bar
```

Is it possible to overwrite this variable during the makefile call? Somthing like the following:

```
FOO=/path/to/foo make all
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The ways that variables get assigned values is specified in the [How Variables Get Their Values](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Values) section of the GNU make Manual.

> Variables can get values in several different ways:
>
> - You can specify an overriding value when you run make. See [Overriding Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding).
> - You can specify a value in the makefile, either with an assignment (see [Setting Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Setting)) or with a verbatim definition (see [Defining Multi-Line Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multi_002dLine)).
> - Variables in the environment become make variables. See [Variables from the Environment](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Environment).
> - Several automatic variables are given new values for each rule. Each of these has a single conventional use. See [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).
> - Several variables have constant initial values. See [Variables Used by Implicit Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables).

So, as Colonel Thirty Two indicates, you can override variables set in the makefile on the command line.

You can also, if you expect this to be a variable that you want to set persistently, use the `?=` assignment and then environment values for that variable will be used.

Answer (score 44):

Specify them as arguments to `make` as `Var=Value`, like `make FOO=/path/to/foo all`.

```
$ cat Makefile 
Foo = asdf

all:
    echo $(Foo)

$ make all
echo asdf
asdf
$ make Foo=bar all
echo bar
bar
```

Comment: Location relative to target names on the command line doesn't matter. They aren't positional.

Answer (score 4):

You can also simply use the `?=` operator:

```
$ cat Makefile 
Foo ?= asdf

all:
    echo $(Foo)
$ make all
echo asdf
asdf
$ Foo=bar make all
echo bar
bar
```

Comment: This will accept overrides from both env variables and command-line arguments. If you only need the latter, you can keep using `=`/`:=`, and override using `make foo=bar`.